# Change Titles of custom Section view in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a  UITableView with expand and collapse cells when I tap in the sections. Now I want to collapse the cells again when I tap in one of this cells and give the name of this cell to the section up there. I think that collapse is not a problem but I do not know how to change the name. I have done everything programmatically. Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to setup your custom sections? Are you using tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: ?

Comment: Yes, I am using tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: I will post my code tomorrow, I have been busy today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

1. add an observer in custom section view to update title. Because section view is reused in UITableView,need a parameter(such as: int sectionIndex) to definite witch section the section view belong to.
2. in tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: set sectionView.sectionIndex with indexPath.section
3. in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: post a notification with indexPath.section and title string

Comment: I tried to do a UITableViewHeaderFooterView, but it did not work and I was trying to do it with a normal Custom UIView. I am going to try what you say. Today I am busy and I can't try it, but I will. Sounds good what you say. Do you think that I can do what you say using UIView or I should use a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView for the section?

Comment: Ok, so I have done first and second points already, should I pass a dictionary with the indexpath.section and title string in the Notification? Now I did it passing only the string and obviously the title change in all the sections

Comment: Finally I did with a NSDictionary, Thank you.

Comment: Now I only have troubles with Reuse section title when I do scroll in the tableView. section title changes again to the title before

Comment: Found your new question,have new comment in that questiuon.